# Catching exceptions in Dispose during an exception

Tags: c#, exception, using, idisposable

Imagine that in C# (in .NET 4.5.x) that you have a `using` block around an object which implements `IDisposible`.  Imagine that

1. an exception is thrown within the using block
2. when the dispose method is called, an additional exception is thrown

What is the best way to pass the two exceptions to a global error handler?

Code Sample:

```
class SampleClass : IDisposable
{
    void doSomething()
    {
        // Imagine that this code is actually doing something
        // Except that it unexpectedly hits an exception
        throw new Exception("Exception A");
    }

    void Dispose()
    {
       // Imagine that this code is doing some cleanup
       // Except that it is buggy
       // And throws more exceptions
       throw new Exception("Exception B");
    }
}

static void Main()
{
    try
    {
        using(var c = new SampleClass())
        {
            c.doSomething();
        }
    } 
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        // Code that records and reports exceptions
        RecordException(e);
    } 
}
```

In the above example, I want all the details of both `Exception A` and `Exception B` recorded.  What is the best way to pass the two exceptions to `RecordException`?

[This article](http://www.digitallycreated.net/Blog/51/c%23-using-blocks-can-swallow-exceptions) proposes a `SafeUsingBlock` extension.  Is that the established best practice?

**Edit:** In this case I control and can re-write `SampleClass` and `SampleClass.Dispose()`

Comment: You could create your own global exception handler and/or czech out Log4Net, a pretty easy way to log stuff to your heart's [dis]content.

Comment: Dispose() should never ever throw an exception.  Trying to reason "what if it does anyway" is pretty futile and will never make you arrive at the correct solution.  You'll have to postpone with a critical finalizer, pretty unlikely to work out, or pull the plug with Environment.FailFast().  Pull the plug.

Comment: @HansPassant - See my note below about ``Task.Dispose()``

Comment: Related article explaining some options along with the pros and cons: http://www.goland.org/losing_exception/

Answer (score 1):

If you have control of the `Dispose()` method, I'd suggest making it error-proof at all costs. In general, you should be able to rely on `IDisposable`s to `Dispose()` safely.

If this is a class you have no control over, your suggestion of `try` wrapping `using` will work, though, to make it more elegant, I'd probably do something closer to:

```
try
{
    var c = new SampleClass();
    c.doSomething();
    c.Dispose();
}
catch(Exception e)
{
    RecordException(e);
}
```

`SafeUsingBlock()` looks like it gets the job done, but I would not consider it to be established best practice: it's a workaround. Established best practice is for `Dispose()` methods to be safe.

Also, if `SampleClass` is one you have no control over, consider wrapping it in a façade which also implements `IDisposable` and handles errors in the `Dispose()` method, e.g.

```
public class SampleClassWrapper : IDisposable
{
    private readonly SampleClass _target;
    public SampleClassWrapper(SampleClass target)
    {
        _target = target;
    }

    public void doSomething()
    {
        _target.doSomething();
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        try
        {
            _target.Dispose();
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            RecordException(e);
        }
    }
}
```

Then you can safely use your `SampleClassWrapper` in a `using` block without worrying about failures in `Dispose()`

Comment: In general, I believe that one should be able to rely on ``Dispose()`` safely.  However [Task.Dispose()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd270681(v=vs.110).aspx) will throw an exception if the task is not completed.  Thus, if ``SampleClass`` owns a ``Task`` object (i.e. ``private Task _task;``, ``SampleClass`` is then responsible for disposing it.  Thus ``SampleClass.Dispose()`` would have something like ``if (_task != null) {_task.Dispose()}`` which would cause an exception if ``SampleClass`` had bugs in the logic that cancelled ``_task`` in the event of a failure in ``doSomething``

Comment: Ah, that makes sense - but in that situation, you're going outside of the happy-path intended use of the provided `Dispose()` behavior, so having some goofy control structure isn't out of the question. Alternatively, is there another path you can pursue to lean on the `Task` library more? For instance, if your application is terminating and you're cleaning up `Task`s, wire up some [`CancellationToken`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997396(v=vs.110).aspx)s and cancel them as the framework supports?